# How to access request parameters when using facebook unity sdk

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I've decided to integrate new facebook unity sdk, so far I've been using custom web page with embeded unity player.

I've configured Facebook App by enabling "Unity Integration Enabled:" and providing URL of Unity Binary with my application.

Question is: How to access URL parameters in such setup?

For instance If somebody clicks link https://apps.facebook.com/myapp/?inviter_id=123
I'd like to access "inviter_id" from within Unity.
So far I had it implemented in javascrit on my own website containing web player and I just passed it as parameters when calling unityObject.embedPlayer so in Unity I could access it with Application.srcValue
At this moment I'm not providing own website/js only .unity3d file.

Answer (score 4):

This is coming soon in the next SDK update.  It will be available on iOS, Android and Facebook Canvas.

SDK 4.3.3 Update: The SDK now has this functionality for all three platforms: Canvas, iOS, and Android.  Look at `FB.GetDeepLink()`.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.GetDeepLink

Comment: No actual ETA other than it will happen quickly.  We've been patching bugs and been getting really good feedback from developers with each release.

In the mean time you can use something like this to get at the url params

`Application.ExternalEval("u.getUnity().SendMessage(<string name of your GameObject>, <string name of your method in the GameObject>, location.href);");`

have your method take a single string as a param.  You can them parse out the url param you want.

Comment: Hey Brian, I've got the latest version, but I couldn't figure how to access external params.. I mean, if I send a request in my app and a friend accepts it in the facebook app how do I get the launch URL? I couldn't find it anywhere in the docs :(

Comment: Hi, sorry we didn't add it to latest SDK version yet.  We had a solution at first, but found a major bug with it not getting the params every time.  Rather than releasing a half baked solution or hold up the other bug fixes, we pulled it out to find a better way to do it.

Comment: Ohh, that's too bad... I was trying to avoid buying Prime31 plugin for that single reason.. Should I wait a couple more days?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the notification from stack overflow that you replied back.  Next SDK launch will have this and will be out in a few days.  Or if you don't mind getting a early cut that you can code against, you can shoot us an email at unity-sdk@fb.com.  We're still testing it for potential bugs before releasing it publicly so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I found out that best way is to uxecute javascript cod that is passing window.location.href back to Unity:

```
        Application.ExternalEval(
        "UnityObject2.instances[0].getUnity().SendMessage('FacebookCallbackGO', 'InitializeForFacebook', window.location.href);"
        );
```

Comment: This is valid for Canvas only... do you know how to access launchURL in iOS and Android?

Comment: `FB.GetDeepLink()` in version 4.3.3 has a way to get it for all the platforms.